# What is the big o notation of following functions

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I can't figure out the smallest upper barriers for those two functions.

I think ex1 has `O(log_3(n))` and ex5 should have `O(n!)`.
But I'm not actually confident about this, since I haven't truly understood the subject yet.

```java
public int ex1 ( int n ) {
    int r = 0 ;
    for ( int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++) {
        r += n ;
        n = n / 3 ;
    }
    return r ;
}
```

```java
public static int ex5 ( int n ) {
    int r = 1 ;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++) {
            r += ex5 ( n - 1 ) ;
    }
    return r ;
}
```

Comment: For function ex1 --> It definitely would linger b/w O(n) & O(c),where c<n. 

For function ex5. I too m confused. Nice question.

Comment: @AntP : You are talking about which function ? ex1 or ex5?

Comment: i'm talking about ex1 should have something like O(log3(n)) and ex5 should have something like O(n!) but i can't really tell, i'm in desperate need of an explanation for the recursive stuff

Comment: See this video. Video lecture from one of the most competitive and technical schools round the globe.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VF2Q0pgUFI

Comment: Are you talking about the return value of the function, or the time it takes to compute that value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output values of ex5 correspond to [sequence A000522 at oeis.org](http://oeis.org/A000522), which increases as a(n) = Sum_{k=0..n} n!/k! (or n! to a first approximation). Because of the horrible way this function is coded, this is equal to the function's time complexity.

A much better algorithm would be as follows:

```
public static int ex5 ( int n ) {
    return (n) ? 1 + n * ex5(n-1) : 1;
}
```

which is obviously <s>O(n^2)</s> O(n) <sup>(Sorry, it's late and I need sleep!)</sup>.

**EDIT:** As everyone else is saying, the complexity of ex1 is O(log_3(n)), or simply O(log(n)), since log_3(n) = log(n)/log(3), and log(3) is a constant in any base.

Comment: "which is obviously O(n^2)"... isn't it O(n)

Answer (score 1):

In each case you just have to consider how many iterations happen within the `for`-loop.

1. **`ex1 = O(log(n))`** The `for`-loop iterates `log3(n)` times

   `r = n/30 + n/31 + n/32 + n/33 + ... + n/3log3(n)`
2. **`ex5 = O(n!)`** The for-loop iterates `n` times for `f(n)` and each iteration calls `f(n-1)` so the total iterations is `|f(n)| = n*|f(n-1)|`, where `|f(n)| = # of iterations in f(n)`. Using this recursively gives:

   ```
   |f(n)| = n|f(n-1)|
          = n(n-1)|f(n-2)|
          = n(n-1)(n-2)|f(n-3)|
          ...
          = n(n-1)(n-2)...(3)(2)|f(0)|
          = n!
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**The first exercise:**

[image]

**The second exercise (very expensive algorithm, should be avoided):**

*Note that the general case execution is the one factorized by c, while the sole **n!** tells the number of base cases (`ex5(0) == 1`). Summing the both would gave the exact number of recursive calls.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first one will execute till `i < log_3(N)` and this can be said to be `O(log_3(N))`

The second one seems to be recursion of recursions. The function seems to recurse `i!` times for each `i < N`.

```
F(3) = {F(2) + F(1)} + {F(1)}
F(4) = {F(3) + F(2) + F(1)} + {F(2) + F(1)} + {F(1}}
```